# Пронзительно лиричный или пронзительно-лиричный?

Tags: наречия, слитно-раздельно-дефис

> Пронзительно(-)лиричная постановка.

Склоняюсь к написанию раздельно, пронзительно ведь наречие. Очень лиричная постановка, иными словами.

Answer (score 6):

**1. Правило**

Розенталь: http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=49#pp49 § 39. Сложные прилагательные

Возможно **различное написание** одних и тех же определений в зависимости от их понимания. Ср.:
**болезненно-тоскливый** стон (‘слышится боль и тоска’) — **болезненно тоскливый стон** (‘слышится тоска, свидетельствующая о боли’);

**искусственно-напыщенная** поза ("искусственная и напыщенная’) — **искусственно напыщенная** поза (‘искусственно созданная напыщенность’);

**Чем ближе по значению** элементы сочетания основ, чем они синонимичнее, тем заметнее выражается в них признак с добавочным оттенком, что дает основание для употребления сложного прилагательного с **дефисным** написанием: грубо-отталкивающий вид; безгрешно-чистые цветы;

Пример: Звучал горестный, **пронзительно лиричный** дуэт Радамеса и Аиды: "Прости, земля, прости, приют всех страданий… [И. К. Архипова. Музыка жизни (1996)]

**2. Решение**

***Пронзительно лиричная постановка.***

В данном случае значения слов ***пронизительный, лиричный*** разные, поэтому выбираем сочетание "наречие + прилагательное", а не сложное прилагательное с дефисным написанием.

Answer (score 3):

Зависит от того, что вы хотите выразить. Если пронзительность — это характеристика лиричности, то тогда дефис не ставится, так как это наречие, которое характеризует прилагательное. Если эти оба слова характеризуют постановку, то дефис ставится.

Comment: Наречия не пишутся черед дефис с прилагательным.

Comment: Внимательно перечитайте мое сообщение. Я сказал, что если это наречие, то дефис не ставится.

Comment: мне не сказали, характеристика это лиричности или это вся постановка такая....

Comment: Вероятнее всего, слово «пронзительно» характеризует слово «лиричная», и дефис не ставится.

Comment: Да, я убрала его. Спасибо за дискуссию!